# "Multiple-step operation generated errors" in WCF

Tags: vb.net, wcf, adodb, recordset, com+

We got some recordset issues and get error message *“Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value. -  at ADODB.Field.set_Value(Object pvar)”*

In our application we use a Windows Service to run different kind of batch and printout jobs.

Previously the service was calling code in a COM+ component (32 bit), but now service calling code in WCF (64 bit) instead.

When we’re running service locally it’s working fine but not in the test environment, we can not reproduce this issue locally.

Someone with any idea?

Comment: Have you tried googling [Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value. - at ADODB.Field.set_Value(Object pvar)](http://www.google.com/webhp?nord=1#nord=1&q=Multiple-step+operation+generated+errors.+Check+each+status+value.+-+at+ADODB.Field.set_Value%28Object+pvar%29)?

Comment: Yes I have googled it alot, haven't found any similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several problems for this issue.

Multiple step problem was solved by changing from ByRef to ByVal in a function when you pass a value from a recordset and that field is a primary key in a database table.

Reason why it work locally and not in test envioronment was a failure in the msi package.